# Formal definition of “proexample”.

Tags: reference-request, definition, examples-counterexamples

Where in the literature do we find the preferred formal definition of “proexample” as in: the number zero is a proexample for the existential sentence "some integer is neither positive nor negative"? 
The notion of proexample is a kind of dual to counterexample. A universal sentence is false iff it has a counterexample. An existential sentence is true iff it has a proexample.

Where in the literature is the notion of “proexample” formally defined? And what are the main theorems involving this notion? And what questions concerning it remain open?

Comment: What makes you think there is such a word? In any case, this is not the sort of notion that's going to be the subject of theorems and open problems...

Comment: I would expect noone formally defined it within mathematics because it is obvious what the word means from its definition in linguistics.  This is in the same manner as the words "object" or "element" are left without formal definitions in mathematics.  By trying to define things, we either have to take some meanings for granted or we eventually reach a circular definition.  (*also, I generally use the word "example" and have never used the word "proexample"*)

Comment: I had a real analysis professor who often used "example" and "nonexample."  I prefer those and frequently use(d) them while teaching.

Comment: I've never seen this word, and doubt per other Comments it appears with a formal definition in the literature on mathematical logic.  You seem to have your own (informal) definition of it (definition by "proexample"?), so to make the Question meaningful I think you'd have to cite literature that uses it.

Comment: Since 1993, I have found this word and the concept it expresses to be helpful in teaching and in writing up results. One goal is to share it with those who might try it out. Another goal is to determine whether others used it before me. http://philpapers.org/rec/COREIT

Answer (score 4):

I was quite surprised to find that "proexample" is actually a word.   Google turns up, for example (or should that be "for proexample"?)
[Corcoran, J. 2005. Counterexamples and proexamples. Bulletin of Symbolic Logic 11(2005) 460](http://philpapers.org/rec/CORCAP-3).

Are you **that** John Corcoran?  If so, you seem to be the main published user of this word, so **you** are the one who should be answering this question.